# Django: Mongoengine syncdb failed

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

I am using [mongoengine](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/tutorial.html) in my project.When I tried to execute `syncdb` command, I am facing following error:

```
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\dummy\base.py"
raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured."
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured.
Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for moredetails.
```

Here is settings.py code

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy',
    }
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'mongoengine.django.auth.MongoEngineBackend'
)
SESSION_ENGINE = 'mongoengine.django.sessions'


_MONGODB_HOST = 'localhost'
_MONGODB_NAME = 'demo'

conn = mongoengine.connect(_MONGODB_NAME,host=_MONGODB_HOST)
```

I want to use mongodb for user authentication so I need to create user auth collections in Database.Would it be possible in `mongoengine`?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

`syncdb` command is available for relational databases like mysql, postgres etc. If you want to use mongoengine with mongodb, you don't need to run `syncdb`. If you have defined mongoengine documents, they can be used directly for querying. for more details read mongoengine [connect](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/connecting.html). Also look at [defining-documents](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/guide/defining-documents.html#defining-documents) with mongoengine.

Answer (score 2):

`Django` is written to be used with relational databases. What `syncdb` does is creates your tables in the relational databases that you list in your `settings.py` file.

`Mongo-db`, on the other hand, is a non relational database and hence schema-less. `syncdb` does not work here because there are no schemas/tables to generate.

The way you have connected to `mongo-db` using `mongoengine` is correct. Now you just need to create the models and get started. Just remove `DATABASES` and `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` from your `settings.py` file.

Normal Authentication does not work when you have implemented mongo-db. Check out [this link](http://animesh-sharma.me/blog/django-authentication-using-mongodb/) to implement authentication using mongo-db.

Also, further read the [mongoengine docs](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/guide/defining-documents.html#defining-documents) for better understanding.